# Custom Dimension in Universal Analytics for URL ID

Tags: universal-analytics

I am trying to set up a custom dimension in Universal Analytics where the dimension includes a string within the URL as part of the name.  For instance, the URI for the page that I need to render a custom dimension is this:

/job/location/job_title/1153/5544

I need to generate a custom dimension that would read:

Job View 5544 and all the metrics that generate from this.

What additional coding do I need to add to this script to pull that dynamic URL field?

ga('send', 'pageview', {'dimension1':  'Job View{URL ID}'});

Answer (score 0):

Here is some javascript to get the 5th folder of a URL, which I assume is always the job number:

```
d = document.URL;
s = d.split('/');
ga('send', 'pageview', {'dimension1': 'Job View:'+s[7]});
```

Its s[7] as I assume it takes 2 from http://example.com plus the 5 '/' in your stem, but you get the point if it needs tweaking.